# Find the number of positive roots of the equation $\left|\frac{x^2-4x}{x-1}\right|=-x.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, absolute-value

Find the number of positive roots of the equation: $$\left|\dfrac{x^2-4x}{x-1}\right|=-x.$$
The absolute value is defined as $$|x|=\begin{cases}x,x\ge0, \\-x, x<0\end{cases}.$$ So the equation is equivalent to $$\dfrac{x^2-4x}{x-1}=-x \\ \text{OR}\\ -\dfrac{x^2-4x}{x-1}=-x.$$
The first equation has roots $0;\dfrac{5}{2}$  and the solution of the second equation is $x=0$. So according to my calculations, the equation has $1$ positive root, which is not true. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\frac{5}{2}$ is not a solution to the above equation, in fact I think $0$ is the only solution the equation has...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the LHS is non-negative, $x$ cannot be positive.

Comment: Yes, I noted that. Since the LHS is positive, then the RHS also must be positive, so $-x\ge0\Leftrightarrow x\le 0$. We can conclude that the equation has no positive roots. But why isn't actually the equation equivalent to the union of the solutions of the two equations I wrote?

Comment: @Medi: did you notice that this completely solves the question ?

Comment: I edited my comment.

Comment: @Medi: because these solutions are not solutions.

Comment: More accurately, the LHS is *non-negative*, which still implies $x$ cannot be positive.

Comment: @J.G.: you are right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{5}{2}$  does not satisfy your first equation. For $x=5/2,$ you have

$\frac{(5/2)^2-4(5/2)}{5/2-1}$ is negative.

Answer (score 1):

You have$$\frac{x^2-4x}{x-1}\begin{cases}\leqslant0&\text{ if }x\in(-\infty,0]\cup(1,4]\\\geqslant0&\text{ if }x\in[0,1)\cup[4,\infty)\end{cases}$$and therefore$$\left|\frac{x^2-4x}{x-1}\right|=\begin{cases}-\frac{x^2-4x}{x-1}&\text{ if }x\in(-\infty,0]\cup(1,4]\\\frac{x^2-4x}{x-1}&\text{ if }x\in[0,1)\cup[4,\infty).\end{cases}$$So, solve the equation $-\frac{x^2-4x}{x-1}=-x$ and take its solutions from $(-\infty,0]\cup(1,4]$; also, solve the equation $\frac{x^2-4x}{x-1}=-x$ and take its solutions from $\in[0,1)\cup[4,\infty)$.

Comment: A sledgehammer for a problem that can be answered in a blink !

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you clarify how do we get the intervals in first place?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, On the contrary! That is exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: For instance, $\frac{x^2-4x}{x-1}\leqslant0$ if and only if $x-1<0\leqslant x^2-4x$ or $x-1>0\geqslant x^2-4x$.

Comment: @Medi: so inefficient ! A lengthy, error prone and unfinished discussion (in the end, how many roots ?)

Comment: @YvesDaoust, $1$ root $x=0$.

Comment: @Medi $0$ is not considered positive. And you don't tell how you obtain this result using the sledgehammer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I know. I am talking about the roots of the equation in the problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, what exactly isn't clear then? The equation has only one root $x=0$ which is NOT positive.

Comment: @Medi: understood. There is no need to find the roots.